# Eclim autocomplete not working with neocomplete

Tags: vim, omnicomplete, eclim, neocomplete

I am using Eclim and Vim and Neocomplete plugin, but omnifunc does not work for me at all.

It seems that my environment is properly set, because when I try Eclim functions that test its environment then everything seems to be properly configured.

`:PingEclim` yields these results

```
eclim   2.5.0
eclipse 4.5.1
```

`:EclimValidate`

```
Result: OK, required settings are valid.
```

I put this is my `~/.vim/plugin/eclim.vim`, which was autogenerated by eclim installer

```
let g:EclimCompletionMethod = 'omnifunc'

if !exists('g:neocomplete#force_omni_input_patterns')
    let g:neocomplete#force_omni_input_patterns = {}
endif
let g:neocomplete#force_omni_input_patterns.java = '\%(\h\w*\|)\)\.\w*'
```

Filetype seems to be properly edentified, filetype is enabled
`:filetype`

```
filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON
```

It seems that `omnicomplete` is properly invoked as I type, for example `import org.` prints an error

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

Also `<C-x><C-u>` brings

```
E764: Option 'completefunc' is not set
```

Vim info follows

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 11 2015 20:44:58)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-936
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fullscreen      -mzscheme        +textobjects
+cindent         -gettext         +netbeans_intg   +title
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +odbeditor       +toolbar
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +transparency
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
```

Any help?